# Action Button Without Notification - Wear

Tags: android, wear-os

I want to know if it is possible to create this kind of buttons on android wear inside my app (without a notification like on the link).

[image]

http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this view : [ActionPage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/ActionPage.html). You can set the text below, the icon inside, the action to perform on click, etc. Check the documentation for more. 
Here is an example :

```
<android.support.wearable.view.ActionPage
    android:id="@+id/action_page"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textColor="@color/st_grey" />
```

I used it in a GridViewPager : it was in a fragment.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_action, container, false);
    ActionPage actionPage = (ActionPage) view.findViewById(R.id.action_page);
    actionPage.setText(actionText);
    actionPage.setImageResource(iconResId);
    actionPage.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

    return view;
}
```